# How do I prove that the difference between two odd functions is an odd function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Recently I've learned that the difference between two odd functions is an odd function, however, I do not understand how I could prove this. Could someone please show me how this works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the definition of an odd function?

Comment: You could try evaluating $f-g$ at $-x$.

Comment: Next time, you should show what you tried.

Comment: yes I've tried looking for the definition and I know the properties.

Answer (score 3):

Let your odds be $f$ and $g$

With $h=f-g$ we have

$$h(-x) = f(-x) - g(-x) = -f(x) + g(x) = -h(x)$$

so $h$ is odd.

Answer (score 3):

More generally check the definition of an odd function for any linear combination $\alpha f+\beta g$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f $ and $g $ be two odd functions, which means that
$$f (-x)=-f (x) $$ and $$g (-x)=-g (x) $$

let $$h (x)=f (x)-g (x) $$

then

$$h (-x)=f (-x)-g (-x ) $$
$$=-f (x)-(-g (x)) $$
$$=-f (x)+g (x ) $$
$$=-(f (x)-g (x)) $$
$$=-h (x ) $$
Done!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: an odd function is a function that satisfies $f(-x) = -f(x)$. So if $f$ and $g$ are both odd functions, then what is $f(-x)-g(-x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?